# how to get react material mui select countries default value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello I'm using the code below which is from:
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#country-select
to create my countries select dropdown however I can not figure out how to get a default value of the Unite States selected so that when it loads it now longer says select a country but selects the us as the default value. Thank you!

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";

export default function CountrySelect() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="country-select-demo"
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      sx={{ }}
      options={countries}
      autoHighlight
      defaultValue={{
        code: 'US',
        label: 'United States',
        phone: '1',
        suggested: true,
      }}
      open={open}
      onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Box
          component="li"
          sx={{ "& > img": { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}
          {...props}
        >
          <img
            loading="lazy"
            width="20"
            src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
            srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
            alt=""
          />
          {option.label} ({option.code}) +{option.phone}
        </Box>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Choose a country"
          inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
            autoComplete: "new-password" // disable autocomplete and autofill
          }}
          InputProps={{
            ...params.InputProps,
            startAdornment: value ? (
              <InputAdornment position="start" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
                <img
                  loading="lazy"
                  width="20"
                  src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${value.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
                  srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${value.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
                  alt=""
                />
              </InputAdornment>
            ) : null
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// From https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlaskit-mk-2/raw/4ad0e56649c3e6c973e226b7efaeb28cb240ccb0/packages/core/select/src/data/countries.js
const countries = [
  { code: "AD", label: "Andorra", phone: "376" },
  {
    code: "AE",
    label: "United Arab Emirates",
    phone: "971"
  },
  { code: "AF", label: "Afghanistan", phone: "93" },
  {
    code: "AG",
    label: "Antigua and Barbuda",
    phone: "1-268"
  },
  { code: "AI", label: "Anguilla", phone: "1-264" },
  { code: "AL", label: "Albania", phone: "355" },
  { code: "AM", label: "Armenia", phone: "374" },
  { code: "AO", label: "Angola", phone: "244" },
  { code: "AQ", label: "Antarctica", phone: "672" },
  { code: "AR", label: "Argentina", phone: "54" },
  { code: "AS", label: "American Samoa", phone: "1-684" },
  { code: "AT", label: "Austria", phone: "43" },
  {
    code: "AU",
    label: "Australia",
    phone: "61",
    suggested: true
  },
  { code: "AW", label: "Aruba", phone: "297" },
  { code: "AX", label: "Alland Islands", phone: "358" },
  { code: "AZ", label: "Azerbaijan", phone: "994" },
  {
    code: "BA",
    label: "Bosnia and Herzegovina",
    phone: "387"
  },
  { code: "BB", label: "Barbados", phone: "1-246" },
  { code: "BD", label: "Bangladesh", phone: "880" },
  { code: "BE", label: "Belgium", phone: "32" },
  { code: "BF", label: "Burkina Faso", phone: "226" },
  { code: "BG", label: "Bulgaria", phone: "359" },
  { code: "BH", label: "Bahrain", phone: "973" },
  { code: "BI", label: "Burundi", phone: "257" },
  { code: "BJ", label: "Benin", phone: "229" },
  { code: "BL", label: "Saint Barthelemy", phone: "590" },
  { code: "BM", label: "Bermuda", phone: "1-441" },
  { code: "BN", label: "Brunei Darussalam", phone: "673" },
  { code: "BO", label: "Bolivia", phone: "591" },
  { code: "BR", label: "Brazil", phone: "55" },
  { code: "BS", label: "Bahamas", phone: "1-242" },
  { code: "BT", label: "Bhutan", phone: "975" },
  { code: "BV", label: "Bouvet Island", phone: "47" },
  { code: "BW", label: "Botswana", phone: "267" },
  { code: "BY", label: "Belarus", phone: "375" },
  { code: "BZ", label: "Belize", phone: "501" },
  {
    code: "CA",
    label: "Canada",
    phone: "1",
    suggested: true
  },
  {
    code: "CC",
    label: "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
    phone: "61"
  },
  {
    code: "CD",
    label: "Congo, Democratic Republic of the",
    phone: "243"
  },
  {
    code: "CF",
    label: "Central African Republic",
    phone: "236"
  },
  {
    code: "CG",
    label: "Congo, Republic of the",
    phone: "242"
  },
  { code: "CH", label: "Switzerland", phone: "41" },
  { code: "CI", label: "Cote d'Ivoire", phone: "225" },
  { code: "CK", label: "Cook Islands", phone: "682" },
  { code: "CL", label: "Chile", phone: "56" },
  { code: "CM", label: "Cameroon", phone: "237" },
  { code: "CN", label: "China", phone: "86" },
  { code: "CO", label: "Colombia", phone: "57" },
  { code: "CR", label: "Costa Rica", phone: "506" },
  { code: "CU", label: "Cuba", phone: "53" },
  { code: "CV", label: "Cape Verde", phone: "238" },
  { code: "CW", label: "Curacao", phone: "599" },
  { code: "CX", label: "Christmas Island", phone: "61" },
  { code: "CY", label: "Cyprus", phone: "357" },
  { code: "CZ", label: "Czech Republic", phone: "420" },
  {
    code: "DE",
    label: "Germany",
    phone: "49",
    suggested: true
  },
  { code: "DJ", label: "Djibouti", phone: "253" },
  { code: "DK", label: "Denmark", phone: "45" },
  { code: "DM", label: "Dominica", phone: "1-767" },
  {
    code: "DO",
    label: "Dominican Republic",
    phone: "1-809"
  },
  { code: "DZ", label: "Algeria", phone: "213" },
  { code: "EC", label: "Ecuador", phone: "593" },
  { code: "EE", label: "Estonia", phone: "372" },
  { code: "EG", label: "Egypt", phone: "20" },
  { code: "EH", label: "Western Sahara", phone: "212" },
  { code: "ER", label: "Eritrea", phone: "291" },
  { code: "ES", label: "Spain", phone: "34" },
  { code: "ET", label: "Ethiopia", phone: "251" },
  { code: "FI", label: "Finland", phone: "358" },
  { code: "FJ", label: "Fiji", phone: "679" },
  {
    code: "FK",
    label: "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",
    phone: "500"
  },
  {
    code: "FM",
    label: "Micronesia, Federated States of",
    phone: "691"
  },
  { code: "FO", label: "Faroe Islands", phone: "298" },
  {
    code: "FR",
    label: "France",
    phone: "33",
    suggested: true
  },
  { code: "GA", label: "Gabon", phone: "241" },
  { code: "GB", label: "United Kingdom", phone: "44" },
  { code: "GD", label: "Grenada", phone: "1-473" },
  { code: "GE", label: "Georgia", phone: "995" },
  { code: "GF", label: "French Guiana", phone: "594" },
  { code: "GG", label: "Guernsey", phone: "44" },
  { code: "GH", label: "Ghana", phone: "233" },
  { code: "GI", label: "Gibraltar", phone: "350" },
  { code: "GL", label: "Greenland", phone: "299" },
  { code: "GM", label: "Gambia", phone: "220" },
  { code: "GN", label: "Guinea", phone: "224" },
  { code: "GP", label: "Guadeloupe", phone: "590" },
  { code: "GQ", label: "Equatorial Guinea", phone: "240" },
  { code: "GR", label: "Greece", phone: "30" },
  {
    code: "GS",
    label: "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",
    phone: "500"
  },
  { code: "GT", label: "Guatemala", phone: "502" },
  { code: "GU", label: "Guam", phone: "1-671" },
  { code: "GW", label: "Guinea-Bissau", phone: "245" },
  { code: "GY", label: "Guyana", phone: "592" },
  { code: "HK", label: "Hong Kong", phone: "852" },
  {
    code: "HM",
    label: "Heard Island and McDonald Islands",
    phone: "672"
  },
  { code: "HN", label: "Honduras", phone: "504" },
  { code: "HR", label: "Croatia", phone: "385" },
  { code: "HT", label: "Haiti", phone: "509" },
  { code: "HU", label: "Hungary", phone: "36" },
  { code: "ID", label: "Indonesia", phone: "62" },
  { code: "IE", label: "Ireland", phone: "353" },
  { code: "IL", label: "Israel", phone: "972" },
  { code: "IM", label: "Isle of Man", phone: "44" },
  { code: "IN", label: "India", phone: "91" },
  {
    code: "IO",
    label: "British Indian Ocean Territory",
    phone: "246"
  },
  { code: "IQ", label: "Iraq", phone: "964" },
  {
    code: "IR",
    label: "Iran, Islamic Republic of",
    phone: "98"
  },
  { code: "IS", label: "Iceland", phone: "354" },
  { code: "IT", label: "Italy", phone: "39" },
  { code: "JE", label: "Jersey", phone: "44" },
  { code: "JM", label: "Jamaica", phone: "1-876" },
  { code: "JO", label: "Jordan", phone: "962" },
  {
    code: "JP",
    label: "Japan",
    phone: "81",
    suggested: true
  },
  { code: "KE", label: "Kenya", phone: "254" },
  { code: "KG", label: "Kyrgyzstan", phone: "996" },
  { code: "KH", label: "Cambodia", phone: "855" },
  { code: "KI", label: "Kiribati", phone: "686" },
  { code: "KM", label: "Comoros", phone: "269" },
  {
    code: "KN",
    label: "Saint Kitts and Nevis",
    phone: "1-869"
  },
  {
    code: "KP",
    label: "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",
    phone: "850"
  },
  { code: "KR", label: "Korea, Republic of", phone: "82" },
  { code: "KW", label: "Kuwait", phone: "965" },
  { code: "KY", label: "Cayman Islands", phone: "1-345" },
  { code: "KZ", label: "Kazakhstan", phone: "7" },
  {
    code: "LA",
    label: "Lao People's Democratic Republic",
    phone: "856"
  },
  { code: "LB", label: "Lebanon", phone: "961" },
  { code: "LC", label: "Saint Lucia", phone: "1-758" },
  { code: "LI", label: "Liechtenstein", phone: "423" },
  { code: "LK", label: "Sri Lanka", phone: "94" },
  { code: "LR", label: "Liberia", phone: "231" },
  { code: "LS", label: "Lesotho", phone: "266" },
  { code: "LT", label: "Lithuania", phone: "370" },
  { code: "LU", label: "Luxembourg", phone: "352" },
  { code: "LV", label: "Latvia", phone: "371" },
  { code: "LY", label: "Libya", phone: "218" },
  { code: "MA", label: "Morocco", phone: "212" },
  { code: "MC", label: "Monaco", phone: "377" },
  {
    code: "MD",
    label: "Moldova, Republic of",
    phone: "373"
  },
  { code: "ME", label: "Montenegro", phone: "382" },
  {
    code: "MF",
    label: "Saint Martin (French part)",
    phone: "590"
  },
  { code: "MG", label: "Madagascar", phone: "261" },
  { code: "MH", label: "Marshall Islands", phone: "692" },
  {
    code: "MK",
    label: "Macedonia, the Former Yugoslav Republic of",
    phone: "389"
  },
  { code: "ML", label: "Mali", phone: "223" },
  { code: "MM", label: "Myanmar", phone: "95" },
  { code: "MN", label: "Mongolia", phone: "976" },
  { code: "MO", label: "Macao", phone: "853" },
  {
    code: "MP",
    label: "Northern Mariana Islands",
    phone: "1-670"
  },
  { code: "MQ", label: "Martinique", phone: "596" },
  { code: "MR", label: "Mauritania", phone: "222" },
  { code: "MS", label: "Montserrat", phone: "1-664" },
  { code: "MT", label: "Malta", phone: "356" },
  { code: "MU", label: "Mauritius", phone: "230" },
  { code: "MV", label: "Maldives", phone: "960" },
  { code: "MW", label: "Malawi", phone: "265" },
  { code: "MX", label: "Mexico", phone: "52" },
  { code: "MY", label: "Malaysia", phone: "60" },
  { code: "MZ", label: "Mozambique", phone: "258" },
  { code: "NA", label: "Namibia", phone: "264" },
  { code: "NC", label: "New Caledonia", phone: "687" },
  { code: "NE", label: "Niger", phone: "227" },
  { code: "NF", label: "Norfolk Island", phone: "672" },
  { code: "NG", label: "Nigeria", phone: "234" },
  { code: "NI", label: "Nicaragua", phone: "505" },
  { code: "NL", label: "Netherlands", phone: "31" },
  { code: "NO", label: "Norway", phone: "47" },
  { code: "NP", label: "Nepal", phone: "977" },
  { code: "NR", label: "Nauru", phone: "674" },
  { code: "NU", label: "Niue", phone: "683" },
  { code: "NZ", label: "New Zealand", phone: "64" },
  { code: "OM", label: "Oman", phone: "968" },
  { code: "PA", label: "Panama", phone: "507" },
  { code: "PE", label: "Peru", phone: "51" },
  { code: "PF", label: "French Polynesia", phone: "689" },
  { code: "PG", label: "Papua New Guinea", phone: "675" },
  { code: "PH", label: "Philippines", phone: "63" },
  { code: "PK", label: "Pakistan", phone: "92" },
  { code: "PL", label: "Poland", phone: "48" },
  {
    code: "PM",
    label: "Saint Pierre and Miquelon",
    phone: "508"
  },
  { code: "PN", label: "Pitcairn", phone: "870" },
  { code: "PR", label: "Puerto Rico", phone: "1" },
  {
    code: "PS",
    label: "Palestine, State of",
    phone: "970"
  },
  { code: "PT", label: "Portugal", phone: "351" },
  { code: "PW", label: "Palau", phone: "680" },
  { code: "PY", label: "Paraguay", phone: "595" },
  { code: "QA", label: "Qatar", phone: "974" },
  { code: "RE", label: "Reunion", phone: "262" },
  { code: "RO", label: "Romania", phone: "40" },
  { code: "RS", label: "Serbia", phone: "381" },
  { code: "RU", label: "Russian Federation", phone: "7" },
  { code: "RW", label: "Rwanda", phone: "250" },
  { code: "SA", label: "Saudi Arabia", phone: "966" },
  { code: "SB", label: "Solomon Islands", phone: "677" },
  { code: "SC", label: "Seychelles", phone: "248" },
  { code: "SD", label: "Sudan", phone: "249" },
  { code: "SE", label: "Sweden", phone: "46" },
  { code: "SG", label: "Singapore", phone: "65" },
  { code: "SH", label: "Saint Helena", phone: "290" },
  { code: "SI", label: "Slovenia", phone: "386" },
  {
    code: "SJ",
    label: "Svalbard and Jan Mayen",
    phone: "47"
  },
  { code: "SK", label: "Slovakia", phone: "421" },
  { code: "SL", label: "Sierra Leone", phone: "232" },
  { code: "SM", label: "San Marino", phone: "378" },
  { code: "SN", label: "Senegal", phone: "221" },
  { code: "SO", label: "Somalia", phone: "252" },
  { code: "SR", label: "Suriname", phone: "597" },
  { code: "SS", label: "South Sudan", phone: "211" },
  {
    code: "ST",
    label: "Sao Tome and Principe",
    phone: "239"
  },
  { code: "SV", label: "El Salvador", phone: "503" },
  {
    code: "SX",
    label: "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)",
    phone: "1-721"
  },
  {
    code: "SY",
    label: "Syrian Arab Republic",
    phone: "963"
  },
  { code: "SZ", label: "Swaziland", phone: "268" },
  {
    code: "TC",
    label: "Turks and Caicos Islands",
    phone: "1-649"
  },
  { code: "TD", label: "Chad", phone: "235" },
  {
    code: "TF",
    label: "French Southern Territories",
    phone: "262"
  },
  { code: "TG", label: "Togo", phone: "228" },
  { code: "TH", label: "Thailand", phone: "66" },
  { code: "TJ", label: "Tajikistan", phone: "992" },
  { code: "TK", label: "Tokelau", phone: "690" },
  { code: "TL", label: "Timor-Leste", phone: "670" },
  { code: "TM", label: "Turkmenistan", phone: "993" },
  { code: "TN", label: "Tunisia", phone: "216" },
  { code: "TO", label: "Tonga", phone: "676" },
  { code: "TR", label: "Turkey", phone: "90" },
  {
    code: "TT",
    label: "Trinidad and Tobago",
    phone: "1-868"
  },
  { code: "TV", label: "Tuvalu", phone: "688" },
  {
    code: "TW",
    label: "Taiwan, Province of China",
    phone: "886"
  },
  {
    code: "TZ",
    label: "United Republic of Tanzania",
    phone: "255"
  },
  { code: "UA", label: "Ukraine", phone: "380" },
  { code: "UG", label: "Uganda", phone: "256" },
  {
    code: "US",
    label: "United States",
    phone: "1",
    suggested: true
  },
  { code: "UY", label: "Uruguay", phone: "598" },
  { code: "UZ", label: "Uzbekistan", phone: "998" },
  {
    code: "VA",
    label: "Holy See (Vatican City State)",
    phone: "379"
  },
  {
    code: "VC",
    label: "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",
    phone: "1-784"
  },
  { code: "VE", label: "Venezuela", phone: "58" },
  {
    code: "VG",
    label: "British Virgin Islands",
    phone: "1-284"
  },
  {
    code: "VI",
    label: "US Virgin Islands",
    phone: "1-340"
  },
  { code: "VN", label: "Vietnam", phone: "84" },
  { code: "VU", label: "Vanuatu", phone: "678" },
  { code: "WF", label: "Wallis and Futuna", phone: "681" },
  { code: "WS", label: "Samoa", phone: "685" },
  { code: "XK", label: "Kosovo", phone: "383" },
  { code: "YE", label: "Yemen", phone: "967" },
  { code: "YT", label: "Mayotte", phone: "262" },
  { code: "ZA", label: "South Africa", phone: "27" },
  { code: "ZM", label: "Zambia", phone: "260" },
  { code: "ZW", label: "Zimbabwe", phone: "263" }
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to remove value from your code because you are using hook
for value,
You must to set only default value**

```
   <Autocomplete
          id="country-select-demo"
    **remove this ---->**     value={value}
      **remove this ---->**    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            setValue(newValue);
          }}
          sx={{ }}
          options={countries}
          autoHighlight
          defaultValue={{
            code: 'US',
            label: 'United States',
            phone: '1',
            suggested: true,
          }}
          open={open}
          onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
          onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
....
/>
```

**use submit form to get the value from your autocomplete**

Comment: your wlc ;) have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

In the `Autocomplete` docs it looks like there's a `defaultValue` prop you can use, like this:

```
<Autocomplete
  id="country-select-demo"
  options={countries}
  defaultValue={{
    code: 'AE',
    label: 'United Arab Emirates',
    phone: '971',
  }}
  ...{otherProps}
/>
```

So I believe you can just separate out whatever you want as the default (I think you want the US data) and set that in that prop.

Here's an example sandbox using that prop: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-banzai-4p7974 (check out the `demo.tsx` file)

Comment: I updated my code above with what you suggested however it doesn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: have you removed hooks from your autocomplete ?

Comment: <Autocomplete
            id="country-select-demo"
            options={countries}
            defaultValue={
              countries.filter((res) =>
                props.user.country!.startsWith(res.label)
              )[0]
            }
            autoHighlight
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label + " - +" + option.phone}
 ...

          />
i have code like this its work property

Comment: Ooh good catch @JawadFadel! I went offline a while, glad you could help Robert fix up the rest of the props 